# querying month, day and year in a date

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my situation i have a date field in mySQL, and i used to get the value to variable through the code below. This is right when i query a complete date such as "08-28-1989".

mySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM content 
where dateReceived='{$approved_date}' 
and description='{$description}'
```

PHP:

```
   $approved_year   = $_POST["approved_year"];
   $approved_month  = $_POST["approved_month"];
   $approved_day    = $_POST["approved_day"];
   $approved_dt = strtotime($approved_year."-".$approved_month."-".$approved_day);
                    $approved_date  = date("Y-m-d",$approved_dt);
```

How can I make it more dynamic if i say the user only input "08" (Month only) then it displays all records in that month regardless of day and year. Or the user will just input the month and the year and it just query it to my database.

Here's my HTML also:

```
<p>
            Date Approved
            <select name="approved_month">
            <?php
                $month = array(" ","January","February","March","April",
                               "May","June","July","August",
                                "Septembe","October","November","December");
                for($x=0;$x<12;$x++){
                    echo "<option value=\"".$x."\">".$month[$x]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="approved_day" value="" size="2" />
            <input type="text" name="approved_year" value="" size="10" />
</p>
```

Comment: show us your database query that you are using to fetch result by date.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it on mysql side is to use [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE MONTH(date) = 5;

SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE MONTH(date) = 5
   AND YEAR(date) = 2013;
```

**Note:** the drawback of such approach (using functions on `date` column) is that no indices will be used on `date` column.

The second query can be rewritten using [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31';
```

First date and last date of the month for such query can be easily built in php with [relative date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8301c/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

You could take the date and break it up into seperate fields in your database. Day, month, and year. 
Break up the date with explode:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$explodedDate = explode("-", $date);
$year = $explodedDate[0];
$month = $explodedDate[1];
$day = $explodedDate[2];
```

You can then insert the seperate date attributes into your database and then use mysqli query to display the results you need based on user input. ie:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE month = $userEnteredMonth";
```